# emacs + dirtree work like normal file browser

Tags: emacs

I am new to emacs, and I tried dirtree like this picture:
I use `m-x dirtree` and it shows up the left frame.
http://db.tt/IbN9UaJR

But when I click on the file, it open the file in left frame/buffer?...
the file content replace the dirtree itself.

and I want it works like normal file browser like textwranger:
http://db.tt/H14KsUsD

How can I do this?
Moreoever, How to make dirtree open automatically when start emacs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are using this: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dirtree.el

This function you are looking for seems to be `dirtree-select` you should bind it to the appropriate key or mouse button. The function you are using now is `dirtree-open` which is bound to `C-o`. The file also has an example how to map keys in a modemap.

HTH.

Comment: yes, I use this link you paste. and after play it around,
I think it does not match what I want,
looks like it can't expand the folder tree but display what it contain in the right frame..:http://db.tt/miXNUQsd
I should try other extensions....

Comment: @CSJ May I recommend dired? It comes bundled with Emacs and is highly effective. If you found this useful, please vote it up for others to see or answer your own question if you think it is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the **"Tree"** menu when on the dirtree buffer, you'll find many options including **"Toggle expand"**. You can choose that or just press *'e'* when on the appropriate folder and dirtree will expand that folder. You can also use "Expand to level [1|2]" to have more control.